# Solving Laplace Transform IVP

Tags: differential-equations, integral-transforms

I want to solve the IVP Laplace transform for the following:

$$y''-2y'+y=3e^t$$ with $$y(0)=1, \; y'(0)=1.$$

How would I input this in Wolfram Language? I've tried a bunch of different things and nothing seems to work!

I want to eventually arrive at its inverse which I know to be $$y=e^t + (3e^ts^2)/2.$$

Comment: Examples solving ODE with Laplace transform can be found in **Applications** section of document of `LaplaceTransform`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYg9I.png. "I've tried a bunch of different things and nothing seems to work!" How did you try? Please show us your failed trial so we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: this ode has unique solution. So you get same solution if you use just `DSolve[{ode, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, y[t], t]` or use Laplace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking cue from the documentation:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

LaplaceTransform[y''[t] - 2 y'[t] + y[t] == 3 Exp[t], t, 
  s] /. {y[0] -> 1, y'[0] -> 1}

lt = Solve[%, LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s]]
```

> {{LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s] -> (4 - 2 s + s^2)/(-1 + s)^3}}

```
sol = InverseLaplaceTransform[lt, s, t]
```

$\left\{\left\{y(t)\to \frac{1}{2} e^t \left(3 t^2+2\right)\right\}\right\}$

```
Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```